# Why am I having trouble with polymorphism and interfaces in Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I've been trying to get interaction going in my game, but I'm doing something wrong and I don't know where! I'll include a bunch of code below and omit irrelevant bits.

I create the interface in the engine. The resulting class is called **IInteract**. It contains just one function called **void Interact(ACharacterBase* Caller)**. **ACharacterBase** is just the default pawn for my project. Here's the header file for **IInteract**.

```
#pragma once

#include "STRGZR/Characters/CharacterBase.h"

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "UObject/Interface.h"
#include "Interact.generated.h"

// This class does not need to be modified.
UINTERFACE(MinimalAPI)
class UInteract : public UInterface
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
};

/**
 * 
 */
class STRGZR_API IInteract
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    // Add interface functions to this class. This is the class that will be inherited to implement this interface.
public:
    void Interact(ACharacterBase* Caller);
};
```

Now, I made another class called **AInteractable** and I implemented **IInteract** into **AInteractable**. Then I declared **Interact(ACharacterBase* Caller)** from the interface. Here's the code for **AInteractable**.

```
#pragma once

#include "Interact.h"
#include "STRGZR/Characters/CharacterBase.h"

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Interactable.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class STRGZR_API AInteractable : public AActor, public IInteract
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AInteractable();

protected:
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)
    void Interact(ACharacterBase* Caller);

public:
};
```

And here's the definition for **void Interact(ACharacterBase* Caller)**.

```
#include "Interactable.h"

// Sets default values
AInteractable::AInteractable()
{

}

void AInteractable::Interact(ACharacterBase* Caller)
{
    Destroy();
}
```

I guess my first question is, where should I be using *virtual* and *override* keywords on the interact function in **AInteractable** and **IInteract**?

Now, I set up key binding so that a **OnInteract** in **ACharacterBase** is called when the interact key is pressed. Here's the code file for **ACharacterBase**.

```
#include "GameFramework/CharacterMovementComponent.h"
#include "STRGZR/Interactable/Interact.h"

#include "CharacterBase.h"

// Sets default values
ACharacterBase::ACharacterBase()
{   
    LineTraceLength = 2000.f;
}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void ACharacterBase::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

    // Set up gameplay key bindings
    check(PlayerInputComponent);

    // Bind Interact event
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Interact", IE_Pressed, this, &ACharacterBase::OnInteract);
}

FHitResult ACharacterBase::LineTraceForward()
{
    FHitResult HitResult;
    FCollisionQueryParams CollisionQueryParams;
    FVector CharacterLocation;
    FRotator CharacterRotation;

    GetActorEyesViewPoint(CharacterLocation, CharacterRotation);

    FVector Start = CharacterLocation;
    FVector End = CharacterLocation + (CharacterRotation.Vector() * LineTraceLength);


    ActorLineTraceSingle(HitResult, Start, End, ECC_Visibility, CollisionQueryParams);

    return HitResult;
}

void ACharacterBase::OnInteract()
{
    AActor* InteractedActor = LineTraceForward().GetActor();

    IInteract* Interface = Cast<IInteract>(InteractedActor);

    if (Interface)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Cast successful"))
    }
}
```

Here's the header file for **ACharacterBase** too.

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "CharacterBase.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class STRGZR_API ACharacterBase : public ACharacter
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this character's properties
    ACharacterBase();

protected:
    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "Interaction")
    FHitResult LineTraceForward();

    UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable, Category = "Input")
    void OnInteract();

public: 
    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;
};
```

I don't know why, but the cast is failing here:

```
AActor* InteractedActor = LineTraceForward().GetActor();

    IInteract* Interface = Cast<IInteract>(InteractedActor);

    if (Interface)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Cast successful"))
    }
```

My second question is why isn't this cast working and is there a better way to call **Interact(ACharacterBase* Caller)** on **AInteractable**?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `virtual` and `override`

Here's basic usage of dynamic polymorphism:

```
class IInterface {
public:
virtual void method() = 0;
};

class CClass : public IInterface {
public:
void method() override { // do smth }
};

int main() { 
    IInterface* ptr = new CClass();
    ptr->method();
}
```

(Do not forget to delete ptr or use reference counting)

You can read about virtual methods here:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override

As for `Cast<T>` - I'm not familiar with Unreal Engine, however it [appears](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/CoreUObject/Templates/Cast/1/index.html) to be some kind of `dynamic_cast<T>`. You cannot perform polymorphic casts without class having virtual table inside, which is provided by definition of `virtual` method (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Polymorphic_objects
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

Comment: `IInterface`s are not quite interfaces, `Cast` is not quite `dynamic_cast` and Unreal is not quite c++.

Answer (score 0):

- You should put the `UFUNCTION(BlueprintCallable)` specifier on the function declaration inside `IInteract`, not on the implementing actor.
- The implementing actor should override using this declaration:

  `void Interact_Implementation(ACharacterBase* Caller) override;`
- You should not check if an actor implements an interface by using `Cast`, but by calling:

  `actor->Implements<UInteract>()`
- You should call interface methods using:

  `IInterface::Execute_Interact(someInteractable, caller)`

So you should never have a reason to cast to an interface.

Also, you haven't verified that your line trace is actually hitting an `AInteractable` actor.

Comment: I did everything you said, but I'm getting a `member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member` when i add `override` to `Interact_Implementation`. The code compiles and runs fine without the `override` keyword though.

Also, I can't seem to call `Interact` on `Interactable` with `IInterface::Execute_Interact(someInteractable, caller)'. The code compiles, but nothing happens when that line is called. I'm wondering if these two things are linked somehow. Thanks!

Comment: I rechecked, my syntax was based on having the method in the interface as `UFUNCTION(BlueprintNativeEvent)`. I'm not sure what it would be with `BlueprintCallable`. I would try marking the base method as `virtual`, and overriding it without the `_Implementation` suffix.